# Unable to run javac in a method importing a class in a jar

Tags: java, jar, javac

I want to compile Entry.java which imports a Utilities JAR.

I'm trying to run `javac` in the `Entry.java` to create its class file. But every time I get the `package utilities does not exist` error.
I tried this command from the Project folder, but it didn't work: `javac .\main\Entry.java`.

The directory structure is this:

- Project

  - Manifest.txt
  - main

    - Entry.java
  - utilities

    - Utilities.jar

Entry.java is a simple file importing Utilities (a JAR file):

```
package main;

import utilities.Utilities;

public class Entry{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Utilities.word());
    }
}
```

Utilities.java has only a method that returns a string:

```
package utilities;

public class Utilities{
    public static String word (){
        return "Utilities";
    }
}
```

If I understood correctly if I run `javac` from the top directory (called Project) all the subdirectories will be in the CLASSPATH, so I don't need `-cp` here. I would need it if I run `javac` from inside the main directory.

(But I've tried anyway. But `javac -cp .\utilities\Utilities.jar .\Entry.java` didn't work as well)

So the whether the problem is the import or I didn't actually understand how to work with JAR files.

Or none of the above.

Comment: I notice you class is called `Utilities` and not `Utils`
Also, when you run Javac it will not create a jar, only the classes

Comment: Please check the `Utils` -> `Utilities` confusion. In your `Main` you refer to `Utils`, you mention a `Utils.java`, yet the code you posted defines a `Utilities`.

Comment: You were right. I correct the names. I copied the old file mistakenly.
I might have expressed myself badly. I want to generate a JAR of the project, but I'm having an issue before that step. I can't create the class file of Entry.java

Comment: I refactored the question a little